# Using WHERE query for a datetime field with pyodbc and Excel.

Tags: python, sql, excel, datetime, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to connect to an Excel file. There is a datetime field in one of the columns in the Excel sheet. I would like to use a query to filter to specific dates, however I have not gotten it to work. Does anyone know how I should format my query with pyodbc to get this to work?

So far I have tried:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT [Data/time] FROM [data_5min$] WHERE [Data/time] = ' + chr(39) + '2010-01-01' + chr(39))
cursor.execute('SELECT [Data/time] FROM [data_5min$] WHERE [Data/time] = 2010-01-01') 
cursor.execute('SELECT [Data/time] FROM [data_5min$] WHERE [Data/time] = (datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0), )')
cursor.execute('SELECT [Data/time] FROM [data_5min$] WHERE [Data/time] = [1/1/2012 0:01]')
```

None of these work. The errors in that respective order are:

1. Data type mismatch
2. No error but no records returned
3. Missing operator
4. Too few parameters

Note: I realize that my field is [Data/time] rather than [Date/time]. It is not a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I got it.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT [Data/time] FROM [data_5min$] WHERE [Data/time] = #1/1/2010#')
```